# Using AVSpeechSynthesizer/AVSpeechUtterance for Text-To-Speech will not work if SpeakSelection is not enabled in device's Accessiblity settings

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

I use AVSpeechSynthesizer and AVSpeechUtterance for text-to-speech.
It works fine, but the User must enable SpeakSelection feature in his/her device's accessibility settings.
Is there a way to do it for them, or at least check the settings and warn them?

Comment: While this is a tad old, a comment: this is not correct as i have speech working with the settings off, using standard code. Where i have troubles is with older hardware that does not support speech. Finding the correct checks ahead of time is hard sleuthing it seems. I cannot user utterance.voice == nil as this is already the case, and the app uses the system default. Info seems sparse regarding when, why and how a voice is downloaded and available.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to say something, attach delegate and measure duration of speaking. If duration of speaking out yours text is near zero, user should check settings/download voice or so!