# AVSpeechUtterance Not Working

Tags: ios8, avspeechsynthesizer

In IOS 8 AVSpeechUtterance is Not Working. Every time I use AVSpeechSynthesizer along with AVSpeechUtterance, I get "Speech initialization error: 2147483665". The same code works fine for IOS 7.1 I have a very large text to convert to speech, and using Google TTS won't allow me to use more than 100 characters at a time. How can I implement text-to-speech in IOS 8? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: has anyone else faced this problem?

Comment: I have the problem but not finding any real solution on iOS8.4

Answer (score 0):

See this topic, and linked question also: [AVSpeechSynthesizer iOS 8 Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870545/avspeechsynthesizer-ios-8-issues/)

For me, TTS on iOS work only on real device, not simulator. But iOS8 still have some problems with voices, some workaround mentioned in questions above.

Also, please mention this (user should set some settings): [Using AVSpeechSynthesizer/AVSpeechUtterance for Text-To-Speech will not work if SpeakSelection is not enabled in device's Accessiblity settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181764/using-avspeechsynthesizer-avspeechutterance-for-text-to-speech-will-not-work-if)

Comment: ok thanks, I've gone through these links & will implement accordngly

Answer (score 0):

First import Speech

```
import Speech
```

Secondly define global variable for AVSpeechSynthesizer

```
let speakTalk = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
```

Create function Audio to take input as string

```
func Audio(Input : String)
        {
                let speakText = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "\(Input)")
                speakText.rate = 0.5
                speakText.pitchMultiplier = 1.7
                speakTalk.speak(speakText)
        }
```

call func Audio()

```
Audio(Input : "Hello")
```